# Make SQL column using PHP explode into variable

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I'm having a bit of trouble trying to make my SQL column a variable in PHP.

So my SQL row contains image URL's and are formatted like this:

```
http://www.website.com/image.jpg,http://www.website.com/image2.jpg,http://www.website.com/image3.jpg
```

So now I need to display the first URL in the row.

I have this short line of code:

```
file = '.(explode(',', $cardata["PictureRefs"])[0]).';
```

I am basically trying to give the variable a value of:

```
$file = "http://www.website.com/image.jpg"
```

My current code is obviously wrong however I feel like I must be quite close. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your short hand is correct, but the string encapsulation is simply not required.

```
$file = explode(',', $cardata['pictureRefs'])[0]; // first image SRC
```

Then you can utilize it like:

```
echo '<img src="'.$file.'"/>';
```

Comment: I've just tried this and I'm getting this syntax error: 

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$cardata' (T_VARIABLE) in...`

 Any idea why?

Comment: @PeterHardy Missed a comma after `','`. Check again, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

No problem.

$file=explode(',',$cardata)[0];

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$file = explode(',',$cardata);
$img = $file[0];
```

Comment: No need to introduce that extra variable.